# Como atualizar listbox de outro Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Segue código:

**Class:**

```
public class Louvor
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Form2:**

```
Form1 form = new Form1();

var data = new List<Louvor>();

var files = Directory.GetFiles($@"{pathname}\Músicas")
                         .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                         .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{

    data.Add(new Louvor() { Value = i, Text = files[i].Replace(".txt", "") });
}

form.listBox5.DisplayMember = "Text";
form.listBox5.DataSource = data;
```

Propriedade `listbox5`:

- Modifiers: Public

O código acima acontece nada, ele apena executa e nada acontece. Alguma solução ?

Comment: Não faltou o form.listBox5.DataBind();

Comment: @Evandro você quis dizer`DataBindings()` ?, porque o `DataBind()` não existe.

Comment: Matheus, a propriedade _Modifiers_ do listbox está como pública?

Comment: @Leandro já está como `public`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda é WinForms! tenta form.listBox5.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Text")

Comment: @MatheusMiranda ou  form.listBox5.Refresh();

Comment: @Evandro não funcionou com `form.listBox5.DataBindings.Add("Text", data, "Text")` e `form.listBox5.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

Está ocorrendo um problema no entendimento de instâncias de objetos.

**O que é uma classe?**

A grosso modo, imagine a classe como um projeto de um carro ou uma planta de uma casa, nela temos definido as características (atributos) e ações (métodos) da nossa entidade (nesse caso vamos utilizar o carro para exemplo). Então podemos ter como características a cor do carro, quantidade de rodas, modelo e marca. Como ações podemos ter acelerar, freiar e trocar de marcha.

Quando nós temos um modelo, podemos criar vários carros a partir desse modelo, ou podemos entregar a planta de uma casa para o mestre de obras e criarmos várias casas a partir dessa planta. Essa é a mesma ideia da nossa classe, temos um modelo para criarmos nossos *objetos*.

Cada objeto pode ter sua particularidade, imagine só, eu quero ter um Ford Ka preto, porém você gostaria de ter um branco, isso é possível não é? Basta eu seguir meu projeto do carro e construir dois carros com cores diferentes.

Os objetos seguem a mesma ideia, temos objetos diferentes, criados a partir do mesmo modelo (nossa classe) com características diferentes.

Para criarmos um objeto nós utilizamos a palavra reservada `new`, que solicita que o S.O. nos entregue uma nova instância (um objeto) baseado no modelo da nossa classe.

No código abaixo nós temos dois objetos diferentes, sendo eles `form1` e `form2`:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form1 form2 = new Form1();
```

[image: Referências]

**Seu problema**

Agora que contextualizamos o conceito, vamos para o seu problema da pergunta.

Quando o programa inicia o projeto WindowsForms na classe `Program.cs` estamos criando um novo objeto a partir da classe `Form1`:

```
//Repare que está sendo utilizado o "new", então temos um novo objeto criado:
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Nesse ponto você tem o seu formulário aberto, onde você cadastra, altera, exclui os dados (realiza todas suas operações). Aqui nós temos um objeto que está salvo na memória com todos os dados preenchidos.

Quando você está na sua classe `Form2` você está criando um **novo objeto, uma nova instância** do `Form1` e está preenchendo os dados dela, ou seja, não tem nada haver com seu formulário principal que estava sendo utilizado anteriormente e que está aberto no formulário anterior, pois são **instâncias diferentes**.

Para resolver o problema precisamos utilizar a referência que já existe e alterarmos o conteúdo dela. Para pegar um formulário existente utilize o seguinte código:

```
Form1 form = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;
```

Agora quando você alterar os dados do seu `listbox` você irá ver o resultado normalmente.

**PS:** Ignore o desenho feito no Paint, foi apenas para tentar explicar melhor rsrsrs.

Espero ter ajudado.